# Record wildcards example in the GHC manual

Tags: haskell, record

In the GHC manual, it is said that

```
module M where
  data R = R { a,b,c :: Int }
module X where
  import M( R(a,c) )
f b = R { .. }
```

The `R{..}` expands to `R{M.a=a}`

But I don't see where is a defined. How this code works?

I tried to compile module X. GHC said: "Not in scope: data constructor ‘R’".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That example's module `X` seems quite buggy.  It looks like they meant to achieve something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
module X where
  import M( R(R,a,c) )
  f a b = R { .. }
```

3 bugs:

- missing the extension pragma,
- missing that type and data constructors are imported differently,
- missing any definition of `a` (other than as the field selector) anywhere.